# Комментарии для сайта в ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Посоветуйте как организовать комментарии для сайта в MVC есть ли для этого специализированные пакеты Nuget или скрипты.

Comment: Не понятно, что вы понимаете под "организовать комментарии". Можете пояснить?

Comment: то же самое что и мы с вами сейчас делаем